# Expected function to throw - does not throw

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I wrote a test using `jest` library. This test is asynchronous.

This is my test:

```
test('Should fail because of missing arguments in saving file', () => {
    expect(async () => {
        const awsTestStorage = new Storage({
            aws: {
                accessKeyId,
                secretAccessKey,
                bucketName: AWSS3BucketName,
            },
        });

        const filename = 'StorageModuleTestONLYAWS_WITHTHROW.txt';
    
        await awsTestStorage.saveFile(filename);
    }).toThrow();
});
```

I didn't provide `accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, AWSS3BucketName` because they are private but I do guarantee they are provided in my code.

Further, I am certain that the function `.saveFile(filename)` should throw an error due to my implementation. When I run the test suite, I get failure to the test, because It did not throw any error although in my test I expected it to throw.

I am pretty sure it has something with my bad implementation of async test, but I cant figure out why.

Comment: Async functions always return promises, so they don't throw - you need `expect(...).rejects...` or to make the test function *itself* `async` so you can `expect(await ...).toThrow...`. See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous.

Comment: I got error: `expect(...).rejects is not a function` @jonrsharpe

Comment: It's *not* a function, no; you need to chain your expectation onto that. Look at the examples in the linked docs.